# Маршалинг структур

Tags: c#

Товарищи подскажите что делаю не так!!! есть Dll на С в ней такая функция с структурой

```
API BOOL Scan(DWORD a, DWORD b, DWORD c, PSEARCH_RESULT pSearchResult);

typedef struct 
   {
       BOOL         d;
       DWORD        e;  
       DWORD        f;       
       BYTE         g[16];      
       BYTE         h;                  
       LONG         j;  
       double       k;              
    } SEARCH_RESULT, *PSEARCH_RESULT;
```

Пытаюсь получить значения структуры;

```
[DllImport("reader.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention =      CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

   public static extern bool Scan(uint a, uint b, uint c, ref PSEARCH_RESULT  pSearchResult);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct PSEARCH_RESULT
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte d;
        public uint e;
        public uint f;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 16)]
        public byte g;
        public byte h;
        public long j;
        public double k;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                uint a = 1;
                uint b = 2;
                uint c = 3;
                PSEARCH_RESULT res = new PSEARCH_RESULT();
                 if (!Scan( a, b, c,ref res ))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("FALSE");
                }
                else
                {
                  // ну здесь если функция отработала все значения d,i ....
                }
```

Испробовал много вариантов, это самый простой и  пока безрезультатно!

Answer (score 2):

Неправильно по крайней мере это:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 16)]
public byte g;
```

Попробуйте так:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16]
public byte[] g;
```

Comment: Так я тоже делал много вариантов попробовал!!

Comment: @IGOR: Ну, тогда ошибка где-то ещё. А calling convention точно правильно указано?

Comment: Да правильно!

Comment: @IGOR: Окей. А в чём проявляется проблема?

Comment: В том и дело что компилятор не на что не ругается!! Но функция Scan, если все параметры правильно передали ей, должна вернуть TRUE, а у меня постоянно  FALSE. Вот и  не знаю в чем дело может быть? Сомнения были правильно ли я перевел структуру, передал указатель на структуру!!

Comment: Проблема решилась !! Оказалось просто что я не правильно предал один из параметров (a,b,c)!!

Comment: @IGOR: вот и хорошо, проблема решена.